# Building a point cloud text file from a 3D surface model

Tags: meshlab

I need the point cloud of a 3D object for holography image processing. Is it possible to import a 3D model to meshlab and get the point cloud information text file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a model inside MeshLab and then apply one of the many sampling filters (just type "*sampling*" in the search box). All these filters basically use different strategies to sample points over the surface (e.g. they create point clouds from meshes).
For example:

- **Montecarlo Sampling** chooses the points in a totally random uniform way
  [image]
- **Poisson disk sampling** chooses the points with the constraint that there are no two points closer than a given radius (providing a much more visually appealing distribution)
  [image]

The two samplings shown in the pictures have the approx. the same number of samples (~10000)

Comment: it works. sorry, I am bigger in working with this software, how can I save the point cloud information as a text file?

Comment: Just export the result using a text file format, for example PLY or XYZ are (or have option for being) very simple ascii format.